# How can we get view object outside it's own controller in sap ui5? and how can we access the controls of a view outside it's controller in sap ui5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Suppose I have a view

How can I get a control of this view by Id from a different controller.

I have tried to set up an ID for the view and tried to access the view by 
sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainViewID") in another controller but it didnt work.
It took only the dynamic view id what you can find from the html elements.

Comment: Why would you even want that? Sounds more like an architectural problem.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a control from another view is discouraged and is generally indicative of bad design. 
In case what you need to do is access data in another view or to change a property of a control based on user input, the better method is to bind those properties to a model and then access that model from the second view.
You can do this by attaching the model to the core, thereby making it accessible throughout the application. For example:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
this.getCore.setModel(oModel,"modelName");
```

Alternatively, you can create this model in the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But can we restrict the model to set only for these two views not to the core or other views.